# Can I replace Tab key as the trigger key in autokey?

Tags: linux, hotkeys, autokey

I have recently started using Autokey on a Raspberry Pi.  I have it installed and operating as expected.  The one issue I have encountered for which I cannot find a solution is that I would like to use the backtick key to trigger text expansion.

I have used back tick key previously with other text expansion/hotkey utilities (namely I used it with AutoHotkey on a Windows machine for years).  I prefer to have a trigger key to avoid any unexpected triggers.  I am so used to using the backtick key that I hit it instead of Tab.  I chose the back tick key a decade or more ago for this purpose because I seldom use it (whereas Tab I use constantly).  That muscle memory is a hard thing to go against.

I cannot find this discussed anywhere in the documentation and had no luck searching for an answer around the webs.  I dug around in the Autokey program files, but didn't find anything so far.  Seems like choosing a custom trigger key should be doable.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to solve this in the way I mentioned in my question (setting the backtick key as the trigger rather than the Tab key).  I have however come up with a simple work around.

In all of my abbreviations I include the backtick as the last character.  Doing this in combination with using the 'trigger immediately (don't require a trigger character)' accomplishes what I was seeking to do.

I am still interested to hear if anyone knows how to do this more directly (changing a setting, rewriting part of the program, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

AutoKey has an option to trigger expansions on all non-word characters. The problem is that it does not consider the backtick a non-word character. To change that, you would have to edit the source code and add the backtick to that list.

I'm not sure where that is in the source code, but if you ask on our Gitter page https://gitter.im/autokey/autokey , one of our developers or advanced users may be able to help you.

This still isn't exactly what you want, but it's closer.

You could also replace the tab key with the backtick key in the source code, but that sounds a bit more dicey and might have other side effects.